# How to stop FormMethod.Post when ModelState.IsValid = False

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I noticed that my error handling was not working.

I have this Razor code on **Page1.cshtml**:

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm("Page2", "Page1", FormMethod.Post))
```

In the **Page1Controller.cs** file, I have:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Page2(GenericModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
```

If **`ModelState.IsValid = false`**, the **FormMethod.Post** still redirects to **Page2** with the errors.

### Is there a way to stop this flow if the **ModelState** is **NOT** Valid?

Comment: I believe the issue is how the ModelState.IsValid is computed. It is derived from  `Values.All(modelState => modelState.Errors.Count == 0)` expression which evaluates true if `Values` collection is empty, means even if there is no input. 

Depending on your model, you need to add a condition with another property to check if that's not empty like `if(condition && ModelState.IsValid)`

Comment: @Tushar, I think you are talking about page errors. But, I want to prevent the `FormMethod.Post` when the page is not valid.

Comment: In this scenario we have two options in hand, either use client side validation  or use `middleware/actionfilter`. `Middleware/action filter` would check the state before reaching to the controller and return expected validation message to browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, in addition to the steps provided in most online instructions, the following section must be called on the Razor page (*.cshtml):

```cs
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

After I included it at the bottom of the page, the validation magically stops **Page1** from POST-ing and displays the error(s).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to stop this flow if the ModelState is NOT Valid?

Well, In this scenario we have two options in hand, either use client side validation  or use `middleware/actionfilter`. This would check the state before reaching to the controller and return expected validation message to browser.

**Middleware/Action Filter:**

```
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<ValidateModelStateAttribute>();
});
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
services.AddMvc(validateModelState=> {
        validateModelState.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateAttribute());
       });
```

**Model:**

```
public class GenericModel
    {

       
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A valid Name is required.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** Above `ErrorMessage` would shown while the post request submitted with invalid model and no longer controller would be invocked. It would implied to all controller and model validateion.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I noticed you added the ASP.NET-Core tag to this question, but I have never used ASP.NET-Core. Your solution presents a json text response to the user, and does not use the Required Field Validators that are currently on the Model class for Client Side Validation (yes, I have that now). The above error message **SHOULD BE SHOWN**, but the ActionResult redirects to Page2 no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I got your point. Okay, that's mean you want to display the validation message on the client side as well right?

Comment: Well, if the validation fails (like not filling in their name), I don't want the ActionResult to continue; I want it to stop and show the errors on the page like every other page does.

Comment: In that scenario, only javascript or jQuery can be the options, otherthan, request would hit to controller action. So we may need to get rid of this pattern `Html.BeginForm` and introduce `ajax request` with javascript/jquery. If you interested, than I can update the answer.

Comment: No, I just contract for this company, and I'm not authorized to make large changes. They would like to know why their Required Field Validators on the controls are not stopping the page from Posting like they are supposed to.